# Count amount of odd numbers in a sentence

Tags: recursion, lisp, scheme, sicp

*I am fairly new to lisp and this is one of the practice problems.*

First of all, this problem is from simply `scheme`. I am not sure how to answer this.
The purpose of this question is to write the function, `count-odd` that **takes a sentence as its input and count how many odd digits are contained in it** as shown below:

> (count-odd'(234 556 4 10 97))
>   6

or

> (count-odd '(24680 42 88))
>   0

If possible, how would you be able to do it, using higher order functions, or recursion or both - whatever gets the job done.

Comment: The procedure takes a _list of integers_ as its input, not a "sentence"

Comment: In Simply Scheme a `sentence` is a list.

Answer (score 4):

I'll give you a few pointers, not a full solution:

First of all, I see 2 distinct ways of doing this, recursion or higher order functions + recursion. For this case, I think straight recursion is easier to grok.

So we'll want a function which takes in a list and does stuff, so

```
(define count-odd
  (lambda (ls) SOMETHING))
```

So this is recursive, so we'd want to split the list

```
(define count-odd
  (lambda (ls)
    (let ((head (car ls)) (rest (cdr ls)))
      SOMETHING)))
```

Now this has a problem, it's an error for an empty list (eg `(count-odd '())`), but I'll let you figure out how to fix that. *Hint, check out scheme's case expression, it makes it easy to check and deal with an empty list*

Now something is our recursion so for something something like:

```
(+ (if (is-odd head) 1 0) (Figure out how many odds are in rest))
```

That should give you something to start on. If you have any specific questions later, feel free to post more questions.

Answer (score 1):

Please take first into consideration the other answer guide so that you try to do it by yourself. The following is a **different** way of solving it. Here is a tested full solution:

```
(define (count-odd num_list)
    (if (null? num_list)
        0
        (+ (num_odds (car num_list)) (count-odd (cdr num_list)))))

(define (num_odds number)
    (if (zero? number)
        0
        (+ (if (odd? number) 1 0) (num_odds (quotient number 10)))))
```

Both procedures are **recursive**.

- `count-odd` keeps getting the first element of a list and passing it to `num_odds` until there is no element left in the list (that is the base case, a null list).
- `num_odds` gets the amount of odd digits of a number. To do so, always asks if the number is **odd** in which case it will add 1, otherwise 0. Then the number is divided by 10 to remove the least significant digit (which **determines if the number is odd or even**) and is passed as argument to a new call. The process repeats until the number is zero (base case).

Answer (score 0):

Try to solve the problem by hand using only recursion before jumping to a higher-order solution; for that, I'd suggest to take a look at the other answers. After you have done that, aim for a practical solution using the tools at your disposal - I would divide the problem in two parts.

First, how to split a positive integer in a list of its digits; this is a recursive procedure over the input number. There are several ways to do this - by first converting the number to a string, or by using arithmetic operations to extract the digits, to name a few. I'll use the later, with a tail-recursive implementation:

```
(define (split-digits n)
  (let loop ((n n)
             (acc '()))
    (if (< n 10)
        (cons n acc)
        (loop (quotient n 10)
              (cons (remainder n 10) acc)))))
```

With this, we can solve the problem in terms of higher-order functions, the structure of the solution mirrors the mental process used to solve the problem by hand:

1. First, we iterate over all the numbers in the input list (using `map`)
2. Split each number in the digits that compose it (using `split-digits`)
3. Count how many of those digits are odd, this gives a partial solution for just one number (using `count`)
4. Add all the partial solutions in the list returned by `map` (using `apply`)

This is how it looks:

```
(define (count-odd lst)
  (apply +
         (map (lambda (x)
                (count odd? (split-digits x)))
              lst)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't be confused if some of the other solutions look strange. Simply Scheme uses non-standard definitions for `first` and `butfirst`. Here is a solution, that I hope follows Simply Scheme friendly.

Here is one strategy to solve the problem:

- turn the number into a list of digits
- transform into a list of zero and ones (zero=even, one=odd)
- add the numbers in the list

Example:  123 -> '(1 2 3) -> '(1 0 1) -> 2

```
(define (digit? x)
  (<= 0 x 9))

(define (number->digits x)
  (if (digit? x)
      (list x)
      (cons (remainder x 10)
            (number->digits (quotient x 10)))))

(define (digit->zero/one d)
  (if (even? d) 0 1))

(define (digits->zero/ones ds)
  (map digit->zero/one ds))

(define (add-numbers xs)
  (if (null? xs)
      0
      (+ (first xs)
         (add-numbers (butfirst xs)))))

(define (count-odds x)
  (add-numbers 
     (digits->zero/ones 
        (number->digits x))))
```

The above is untested, so you might need to fix a few typos.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a good way, too.

```
(define (count-odd sequence)
  (length (filter odd? sequence)))

(define (odd? num)
  (= (remainder num 2) 1))

(count-odd '(234 556 4 10 97))
```

Hope this will help~

The (length sequence) will return the sequence's length,
(filter proc sequence) will return a sequence that contains all the elements satisfy the proc.
And you can define a function called (odd? num)